# Problems with the loop of the array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, loops, parse-platform, cycle

I am new in iOS. I am making an app in which i am getting data from Parse back-end all are working fine. My application for the order and delivery of food. I have a cart where I add items. If the product is already in the cart but added it again, it should increase the quantity and not create another one in the basket. I tried to implement it with the aid of loop but it is not working as it should. But the product is added instead of increasing their quantity. I really hope for your assistance.

```
+ (void)addItem:(PFObject *)item {

Cart *cart = [Cart sharedInstance];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [cart.items count]; i++) {
    if ([item valueForKey:@"objectId"] == [cart.items[i] valueForKey:@"objectId"]) {

        NSDecimalNumber *sumQtyNew = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:1 exponent:0 isNegative:NO];
        NSDecimalNumber *sumQty = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:1 exponent:0 isNegative:NO];

        sumQtyNew = [item valueForKey:@"qty"];
        sumQty =  [cart.items[i] valueForKey:@"qty"];
        sumQty = [sumQty decimalNumberByAdding:sumQtyNew];

        [[cart.items[i] valueForKey:@"objectId"] setObject:sumQty forKey:@"qty"];

    }
    else {
        [cart.items addObject:item];
    }
}

NSDecimalNumber *plus = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc]initWithString:[item objectForKey:@"price"]];
cart.totalPrice = [cart.totalPrice decimalNumberByAdding:plus];
```

}

Comment: Are you sure the above code works?  The logic appears to be that every time there isn't a match on an existing item in the cart it will add the new item.  So if you have 15 items in the cart it will add the new item 15 times.  As for why it isn't matching, it seems that the if statement is always evaluating to false.  Try changing `[item valueForKey:@"objectId"]` to `[[item valueForKey:@"objectId"] integerValue]` as well as the other `valueForKey`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had to use `cart.items` as `NSMutalbeArray`, here is another answer

```
+ (void)addItem:(PFObject *)item {
    Cart *cart = [Cart sharedInstance];
    NSMutableArray * cartItems = cart.items
    NSString *objectId = [item valueForKey:@"objectId"];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"objectId = %@", objectId];
    PFObject *existingItem = [[cartItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] firstObject];

    if (existingItem == nil){
        [cartItems addObject:item];
    } else {
        int sumQty = [[existingItem valueForKey:@"qty"] intValue] + [[item valueForKey:@"qty"] intValue];
        [existingItem setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sumQty] forKey:@"qty"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I need!!! Works perfectly!!! **Mahmoud Adam** thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

i would use a `NSMutableDictionary` to store cart items, the key is the `objectId` and the value is the `Item` itself

```
+ (void)addItem:(PFObject *)item {
    Cart *cart = [Cart sharedInstance];
    NSMutableDictionary * cartItems = cart.items
    NSString *objectId = [item valueForKey:@"objectId"];
    if ([cartItems objectForKey:objectId] == nil){
         [cartItems setObject:item forKey:objectId]
    } else {
        PFObject *oldItem = [cartItems objectForKey:objectId];
        int sumQty = [[oldItem valueForKey:@"qty"] intValue] + [[item valueForKey:@"qty"] intValue];
        [cartItems setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sumQty] forKey:@"qty"]
    }
```

Comment: Did as you said. When I add product to cart, error. http://cs627622.vk.me/v627622607/7ad9/Mp-UEsM-VNM.jpg ((

Comment: You didn't change cart.items to NSMutabledictionary, it is still NSMutableArray

Comment: I can't find how converting NSMutableArray to NSMutableDictionary... could you suggest?

Comment: you need to change the `cart.items` type to `NSMutableDictionary` and if you had to use `cart.items` as `NSMutableArray` you need to add another `NSMutableDictionary * itemsDictionary` to work with and at end you assign `cart.items = [itemsDictionary allObjects]`

Comment: I replaced cart.items NSMutableArray to cart.items NSMutableDictionary  but same error [Screen](http://cs627622.vk.me/v627622607/7ae2/nHu7RF2UkCc.jpg)

Comment: I'm posting another answer so that you can use `NSMutableArray`